# Encoding url in php to prevent direct access

Tags: php

There are three steps for user registration on my site and right now the urls for that are similar to:

```
http://www.example.com/register.php

http://www.example.com/registerstep2.php

http://www.example.com/registerstep3.php
```

I was wondering what is an easy way to encode it to something like:

```
http://www.example.com/w^3434SD343f232gihmsdsdwre232
```

The reason I am trying to do this, is I am trying to ensure that users follow steps and don't try to 'trick' the system by directly going to a registration link 3 for example.

Comment: Unless you want to make it extra cumbersome, there is no need to distribute a registration form onto three pages. The obvious technical alternative is to make one script handle all three parts, carrying around the processed form fields as `<input type=hidden>` and proofchecking it in `register.php?step=2` and `?step=3` of course. Or maybe make it Javascript-bound, and simply reveal the three parts one after another. (With displaying the complete form, if JS is disabled.)

Comment: @mario This is kind of a preference thing, don't you think? There can be many reasons for having a three page submission process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is a bad bad bad idea**. Instead of trying to hide the url through simple obfuscation, do a check at the top of the script to see if they can proceed.

In other words, each time they go to a page, **check to see if they submitted the previous page's info. If they haven't, send them back**. Example:

```
if ( !functionThatChecksAndReturnsBool() )
{
    header("Location http://www.example.com/register.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean? the check is done on step 1, then if everything is verified, then clickin the submit button forwards them to step 2, and if everything is verified there they go to step 3... After they have access to these page url's they can simply visit the third page for example, without accessing the first 2...

Comment: I know it seems like I don't understand you, but I promise that what you want to do (while possible through rewrites in htaccess), is not the right solution. If you explain why a user would go through the registration process multiple times, we can definitely answer better

Comment: Because I simply don't want users tampering with trying to access pages out of order, messing with GET variables, etc... it just seems safer that way, knowing they cant access the confirmation page directly, for example, you know?

Comment: are you passing what they send you in the GET string? Store that in $_SESSION, they have zero access to session variables. Then on each page, check if the appropriate session variables are set, and if they aren't you can boot them. This way you can verify that they not only went to the pages in the correct order, but that they filled out the necessary items

Comment: I am using $_SESSION variables. Paypal sends confirmation details using $_GET variables, on the 'thank you page'. I see what your saying though, that makes sense... thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. Sorry if I came off harsh. This is just the kind of mistake that sounds good on paper, but really comes back to bite you. Wanted to throw up huge warning signs for you :-)

Comment: I understand, thanks again! :) will use your header 'redirect' tip.